# Getting error while using socket.io in html tag

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io-1.0

I am learning socket.io from their documentation but I can not solve this error, which I guess appearing due to using the script tag before body end.

This is the image showing the tag I am getting error and here you can also understand my directory structure:
[image]

Thanks in advance, I have tried all earlier solutions I have found on StackOverflow

Comment: can you show app.js?

Comment: also please show the exact error you getting, an image of your code doesn't help.

Comment: are you using socket.io-1.0? as you have tagged the question with it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you need to copy `socket.io.js` to a public folder (something as resources/js/socket.io.js). This is not the preferred way.

Instead, if your Socket.io server listens properly to your HTTP server, it will automatically serve the client file via `http://localhost:<port>/socket.io/socket.io.js`, now you don't need to find socket client js file or copy in a public folder as `resources/js/socket.io.js` & serve it manually.

If still facing an issue then use the following CDN link [Read here for more info](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-installation/index.html)

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-gDaozqUvc4HTgo8iZjwth73C6dDDeOJsAgpxBcMpZYztUfjHXpzrpdrHRdVp8ySO" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: if properly loading and using a shared http instance (i.e socket.io is running) the route will be added for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`, there is no need to copy it to public folders